# Retrieve files from Heroku server

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Ok, so I have lost my files on my local mac.

I have been pushing these files by

```
git push heroku master
```

And the server is up and running fine.

How can I get all my files back from heroku onto my mac?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Consider this a warning to implement a backup strategy of some sort. A common approach is to also push to something like Github.

Answer (score 3):

https://help.heroku.com/FZDDCBLB/how-can-i-download-my-code-from-heroku

> If you have deployed your application via our git push heroku master method, or via Heroku Pipelines, you can download the latest revision from our git servers with:
>
> ```
> heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME
> ```
>
> This will clone the git repository to your machine with the latest code. Please note, this will only include branches that you have pushed to Heroku, which in most cases will only be the master branch.

Comment: Thanks, butI have tried this and I get the error: "Error: You do not have access to app app.  Error: Frobidden ID: Forbidden

Comment: It's unlikely you managed to snag the app name `app`. Put *your* app name in there, and make sure you're properly logged in as the right Heroku account via `heroku login` as well.

Comment: An additional note here, Heroku is not a repo storage service and should not be counted on to recover files. `heroku git:clone` will only work when Heroku's git servers are used, ie you deployed with `git push heroku master`. Deploys done by button or via GH pull requests will not be included in the downloaded repo.